# Implication of an automorphism group of one graph being a subgroup of another graph's automorphism group

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Given two simple connected graphs $G$ and $H$, given that their automorphism groups are non-trivial, is it necessary that if $\text{Aut}(G)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(H)$, then there exists a subgraph $H'\subseteq H$ such that $\text{Aut}(G)\cong\text{Aut}(H')$?

If the answer is no, could I see a counter example, and is there then a sufficient constraint on $G$ and $H$ which does make this true?

If the answer is yes and the proof isn't absolutely monsterous, I'd love a hint towards trying to prove it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be [the $9$-vertex graph with automorphism group $C_3$](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/1315), shown below. Let $H$ be $K_3$, with automorphism group $S_3$.

[image]

Then $\text{Aut}(G)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(H)$, but there's no subgraph of $H$ whose automorphism group is $C_3$. In fact, $G$ is the smallest graph whose automorphism group is $C_3$.

This generalizes to a whole class of counterexamples, where $H$ is a cycle graph. In that case, $\text{Aut}(H)$ is a dihedral group, but there is no subgraph of $H$ whose automorphism group is the corresponding cyclic group.

Comment: Very interesting indeed, if we extend to requiring that G and H are regular, does the answer change?

Comment: By [Frucht's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht's_theorem) we can also find a $3$-regular graph with automorphism group $C_3$ to use in place of $H$.

Comment: Then I do wonder how tight the constraint on the graph needs to be, because if you force H and G to be complete, I think it holds?

Comment: If $G$ and $H$ are both complete, the statement is no longer very interesting. Notably, the statement does not hold just when $H$ is complete, because there are subgroups of $S_n$ that cannot be realized as automorphism groups of $n$-vertex graphs. (E.g. take $C_p$ for the largest prime $p \le n$.) It might be interesting to see if the statement holds if $G$ is complete; in other words: if $\text{Aut}(H)$ has $S_n$ as a subgroup, is there an $H' \subseteq H$ with $\text{Aut}(H') \cong S_n$?

Comment: I've found a counter-example to that as well. Consider the generalized johnson graph $H = J(5, 3, 2)$. Then, the clique number of $H$ is 2, but $S_3$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(H)$ as checked with Sage.

Comment: @Jatns There are other graphs with automorphism group $S_3$ besides $3$-cliques, though, which might be contained in $H$. I am not sure how to find them in your case, because to me $J(5,3,2)$ is the graph of $3$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ intersecting in exactly $2$ elements, and this has clique number $3$: $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$, and $\{1,2,5\}$ are one such clique. Your definition seems to be different.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant $J(5, 3, 1)$. My mistake. I also didn't think about the fact that other graphs may exist with automorphism group $S_3$ besides $3$-cliques haha.

Comment: The easiest solution here is to take a $K_{1,3}$ subgraph: a vertex and its three neighbors. (This is even induced, though it didn't have to be.) For a spanning subgraph, we can take the union of the three paths $123-145-235-124$, $123-245-135-234$, and $123-345-125-134$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your example

Comment: I am describing a subgraph of $J(5,3,1)$ with automorphism group $S_3$.